# String replace during text printout - Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following to print out text as someone types in a form input box:

```
<script>
var inputBox = document.getElementById('company');
inputBox.onkeyup = function(){
    document.getElementById('printchatbox').innerHTML = inputBox.value;
}
</script>
```

This works great however I also want to replace any spaces a user types with an underscore. To do this i've tried the following to do a simple stirng replace but this seems to break the whole thing.

```
<script>
var inputBox = document.getElementById('company');
inputBox.onkeyup = function(){
    var res = inputBox.replace(" ", "_");
    document.getElementById('printchatbox').innerHTML = res.value;
}
</script>
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

You want the value from the input box not the variable you're using. The following should work:

```
<script>
var inputBox = document.getElementById('company');
inputBox.onkeyup = function(){
  var res = inputBox.value.replace(" ","_");
  document.getElementById('printchatbox').innerHTML = res;
}
</script>
```

**EDIT:** As trincot pointed out this will only replace the first occurrence, using a regular expression will help, here's an alternative:

```
var res = inputBox.value.replace(/\s/g, "_");
```

Answer (score 2):

Some issues:

- `inputBox` has the input value in the `value` property, so you should apply the `replace` on that property value.
- `replace` returns a string, so it does not have a `value` property
- `replace` will only replace one occurrence, unless you provide a regular expression with the `g` modifier.

So do like this:

```
var res = inputBox.value.replace(/ /g, "_");
document.getElementById('printchatbox').innerHTML = res;
```